# Python input and functions

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python, but it's not going well. I wrote this, but it doesn't work. I've found examples that do work, but when I compare them I don't get what I'm doing different.

```
def fact(x):
    x = int(input("enter number: "))
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    return x * fact(x - 1)


print(fact(x))
```

I want it to ask for the user's input and then find the factorial of it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `fact` is supposed to take an argument, 'x'. You call `fact(x)` but `x` is not defined. Also, you probably don't want to take input and redefine `x` inside of the `fact` function.

Comment: Take the input outside of the function, or else each recurive function call will ask for the input again.

Answer (score 1):

Asking the user for the input should occur outside the factorial function.

I renamed the user input to `y` here, to make it clear `x` and `y` are different variables.

```
def fact(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    return x * fact(x - 1)

y = int(input("enter number: "))
print(fact(y))
```

Comment: I dont get it, I just copy pasted your code into python3 console and it doesnt work iI get  this when I try to run it.  Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def fact(x):
...     if x == 0:
...         return 1
...     return x * fact(x - 1)
... 
>>> y = int(input("enter number: "))
enter number: print(fact(y))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'print(fact(y))'
>>>

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: if I save it and run it as a file it works if I try to write it in the python console it doesnt, why?

Comment: @marklarbecause the python console takes a line of code, not a whole program.

Comment: According to the lines above, @marklar, you are pasting the last line ("print(fact(y))") at the "enter number: " prompt that appears once you've pasted the "input" line.

Answer (score 0):

if you are executing in console then try in below format, it should work:

```
def fact(x):
    if x == 0:
        return 1
    return x * fact(x - 1)

print(fact(int(input("enter number: "))))
```